# Extract String(s) from big String selected by special characters

Tags: java, android, string

Let's say I have a String like this:

```
Hey man, my name is Jason and I like Pizza. #Pizza #Name #Cliche
```

My question is how to extract all the strings that start with `#` and put them to another string together?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial on [regex](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Try

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)#(\\S*)").matcher(string);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

EDIT:

As you wanted the other strings as well, you may try

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\s|^)#(\\S*)|(\\S+)").matcher(string);

StringJoiner hashfull = new StringJoiner(" ");
StringJoiner hashless = new StringJoiner(" ");

while(matcher.find())
    if(matcher.group(2) != null)
        hashfull.add(matcher.group(2));
    else if(matcher.group(3) != null)
        hashless.add(matcher.group(3));

System.out.println(hashfull);
System.out.println(hashless);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this code working very well for me because I wanted also the rest of the string. Thanks to @Pshemo and @Mormod for helping me with this. Here is the code:

```
String string = "Hello my name is Jason and I like pizza. #Me #Pizza";
String[] splitedString = string.split(" "); //splits string at spaces 
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder newString2 = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i<splitedString.length; i++){     
if(splitedString[i].startsWith("#")){      
   newString.append(splitedString[i]);
   newString.append(" ");     }
else{     
   newString2.append(splitedString[i]);
   newString2.append(" ");     
    }
 }    
 System.out.println(newString2);     
 System.out.println(newString);
```

Comment: BTW `StringJoiner` was added in Java 8

Comment: I don't know (but I suspect that Java 8 classes ware not added to Android yet). My edit was based on lack of `android` tag which gave impression that you would use standard JVM which now should be using Java 8.

Comment: If you want to make your question about android please edit your question to add relevant tag and rollback my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you search for something like this:

```
String string = "ab cd ef"
String[] splitedString = string.split(" "); //splits string at spaces
String newString = "";
for(int i = 0; i<splitedString; i++){
    if(splitedString[i].startsWith("#")){
        newString += splitedString[i];
    }
}
```

mormod

Comment: Avoid concatenating strings `result += newPart` inside loop. Because of this in each iteration you will end up with having to create new string which will have to copy old value and new one. Instead before looping create buffer like `StringBuilder` and inside loop `append` new values to it.